# De Finetti: equivalence a.s. according to which measure

Tags: bayesian, measure-theory, law-of-large-numbers

In Zen`s answer at 
[What is so cool about de Finetti's representation theorem?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34465/what-is-so-cool-about-de-finettis-representation-theorem?noredirect=1&lq=1)
that is concerned with De Finetti's 0 -1 representation theorem, he says that "De Finetti's law of large numbers" states that it holds that for an exchangeable sequence of RVs $\{X_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty }\overline{X}_n=\Theta \quad \quad \text{almost surely}$$

where $\Theta$ is the Random Variable that arises out of De Finetti`s representation theorem.
However it is not clear to me for which measure this equivalence holds almost surely. Is the relevant measure the measure $\mu$ such that  $\mu[\Theta]$ is the prior probability measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analysis ought to be taking place in a general probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{U}, \mathbb{P})$ with a sample space that encompasses both the observable exchangeable sequence $\mathbf{X}:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\infty$ and the parameter $\Theta:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  The statement of interest is then taken with respect to the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$, so it can be stated more formally by defining an event positing equivalence, and then saying that this event occurs with probability one under the measure $\mathbb{P}$.  Formally, this is:

$$\mathbb{P} ( \mathcal{E}) = 1 \quad \quad \text{where} \quad \quad\mathcal{E} \equiv \left\{ \omega \in \Omega \Bigg| \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\omega) = \Theta(\omega) \right\} \in \mathscr{U}.$$

[O'Neill (2009)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1751-5823.2008.00059.x) argues that the best way to form the parameter $\Theta$ in this analysis is to define it as the [Banach limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit) of the sequence $\mathbf{X}$, which means that it exists for all possible real sequences (i.e., it is well-defined) and it corresponds to the [Cesàro limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation) of the sequence when that exists.  That way, the parameter is equal to the Banach limit of the sequence for all $\omega \in \Omega$ (which is stronger than almost sure equivalence), and $\mathcal{E}$ is the event that the Cesàro limit of the observable sequence exists, which occurs with probability one under the condition of exchangeability.

The prior measure $\mu_\Theta$ for the parameter $\Theta$ is formed from the overall measure $\mathbb{P}$ by restricting attention to events relating to the parameter only.  If we take $\mathscr{U}$ to be the class of all Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ (in order to describe events pertaining to the whole observable sequence) then the domain of the measure $\mu_\Theta$ would be the subspace of Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}$ (to describe the parameter).  The event $\mathcal{E}$ would not be in this domain, and so it would not make sense to try to apply the prior measure $\mu_\Theta$ to describe a probability for this event.

Comment: Thanks again for this clarifying answer. If we define with $X_k: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^k$ the outcome of the first $k$ experiments, then
$\mathbb{P}(X_k)$ (the push-forward measure) is the agent`s believe about the first $k$ outcomes. and $\mathbb{P}(\Theta)= \mu_\Theta$, right?

Comment: Not really.  Remember that random variables are mappings from the domain $\Omega$ to some codomain.  The probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ is a set-function whose domain is the class $\mathscr{U}$, which is a sigma-field of subsets on $\Omega$.  The probability measure operates on *events* in the sample space (which are sets in $\mathscr{U}$), not random variables (which are mappings from the sample space to a codomain).  The probability measures for random variables are formed from the overarching measure $\mathbb{P}$ by looking at the sigma-field of events for that random variable.

Comment: ah i meant $X_k(\mathbb{P})$ and  $\Theta(\mathbb{P})$ of course

Comment: That notation also does not make sense to me, since $\mathbb{P}$ is not an element of $\Omega$, so it is not clear how it could be an argument for a random variable.

Comment: (To understand this well, it is necessary to learn a bit of "measure theory". If you have not already done so, have a read up on probability measures and sigma-fields and have a look at how probability spaces are formed on sub-sigma-fields within a larger probability space.)

Comment: With $\mathbb{Q}:=X_k(\mathbb{P})$ I refer to the measure that is defined via: $\mathbb{Q}(A)= \mathbb{P}(X_k^{-1}(A))$

Comment: I was similarily confused when my professor used this notation :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83312/discussion-between-0rangetree-and-ben).

Comment: More specifically, $\mu_\Theta(A) := \mathbb{P}(\lbrace \omega \in \Omega \mid \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^nX_i/n \in A\rbrace)$.  This prior is a defined by the properties of the exchangeable sequence $\mathbf{X}$.  For example, if $X_i = 1$ a.s. then $\mu_\Theta(A) = \delta_{\{1\}}(A)$.  More generally if $X_i = 1$ with a fixed probability $\gamma$ (i.e., the sequence is i.i.d.) then $\mu_\Theta(A) = \delta_{\{\gamma\}}(A)$ which recovers the frequentist case. Generally speaking it is not impossible to infer $\mu_\Theta$ from a realization $\mathbf{X}(\omega)$, even if infinitely long.